# Why is SparkListenerApplicationStart never fired?

Tags: apache-spark

I am writing a Spark application and I need to intercept the status of the running jobs. I implemented a `SparkListener` for this purpose, using the following code:

```
class MyAppListener extends SparkListener {

    override def onApplicationStart(ev: SparkListenerApplicationStart): Unit = {
      println("AAA: Application Start")
    }

    override def onApplicationEnd(ev: SparkListenerApplicationEnd): Unit = {
      println("AAA: Application End")
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I used the following code to start the application and see the events:

```
val appListener = new MyAppListener
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Listener")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
sc.addSparkListener(appListener)
println(sc.parallelize(1 to 10).count)
sc.stop()
```

In the logs, I see the string "AAA: Application End", but I don't see the start of the application.

Configuration:

- Spark version 1.2.0
- Scala 2.10
- local standalone mode or YARN client mode on a cluster (same behavior)

Answer (score 12):

You were adding your listener to spark in the wrong place, When you initiate a spark context, it also starts your application.=> At the point you added your listener, onApplicationStart has already been fired.

Solution: Add your listener to SparkConf.

```
sparkConf.set("spark.extraListeners","your.listener.class")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be great if you add sample code snippet to explain your answer more precisely.