# Child thread not seeing updates made by main thread

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-spark, thread-safety

I'm implementing a SparkHealthListener by extending SparkListener class.

```
@Component
class ClusterHealthListener extends SparkListener with Logging {
  val appRunning = new AtomicBoolean(false)
  val executorCount = new AtomicInteger(0)

  override def onApplicationStart(applicationStart: SparkListenerApplicationStart) = {
    logger.info("Application Start called .. ")
    this.appRunning.set(true)
    logger.info(s"[appRunning = ${appRunning.get}]")
  }

  override def onExecutorAdded(executorAdded: SparkListenerExecutorAdded) = {
    logger.info("Executor add called .. ")
    this.executorCount.incrementAndGet()
    logger.info(s"[executorCount = ${executorCount.get}]")
  }
}
```

**appRunning** and **executorCount** are two variables declared in ClusterHealthListener class. ClusterHealthReporterThread will only read the values.

```
@Component
class ClusterHealthReporterThread @Autowired() (healthListener: ClusterHealthListener) extends Logging {
  new Thread {
    override def run(): Unit = {
      while (true) {
          Thread.sleep(10 * 1000)
          logger.info("Checking range health")
          logger.info(s"[appRunning = ${healthListener.appRunning.get}] [executorCount=${healthListener.executorCount.get}]"
      }
    }
  }.start()
}
```

ClusterHealthReporterThread is always reporting the initialized values regardless of the changes made to the variable by main thread? What am I doing wrong? Is this because I inject healthListener to ClusterHealthReporterThread?

#### Update

I played around a bit and looks like it has something to do with the way i initiate spark listener.

If I add the spark listener like this

`val sparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
sparkContext.addSparkListener(healthListener)`

Parent thread will show **appRunning** as 'false' always but shows executor count correctly. Child thread (health reporter) will also show proper executor counts but **appRunning** was always reporting 'false' like that of the main thread.

Then I stumbled across this [Why is SparkListenerApplicationStart never fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169981/why-is-sparklistenerapplicationstart-never-fired) and tried setting listener at the spark config level,

`.set("spark.extraListeners", "HealthListener class path")`

If I do this, main thread will report 'true' for **appRunning** and will report **correct executor counts** but child thread will always report 'false' and '0' value for executors.

Comment: Did you try setting your variables with @volatile? could be a visibility issue

Comment: Isn’t atomic booleans volatile as well?

Comment: I think this can be because of the lazy evaluation of the expression language in the log. And due to this, the result of the evaluation can be [cached](http://matt.might.net/articles/implementing-laziness/). Give it a try: call healthListener.appRunning.get separately (not in the log statement) and put only the result to the log. Btw what kind of logger is this?

Comment: Try wiring up your application manually and see if that changes anything. `ClusterHealthReporterThread` probably just has a different `ClusterHealthListener` instance than the one that is actually doing the listening.

Comment: @m4gic Sorry for the delayed response. I was using `typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.Logging`. Tried calling healthListener.appRunning.get separately and switched to StrictLogger. Nothing helped.

Comment: @Jasper-M will try that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't immediately see what's wrong here, you might have found an interesting edge case.

I think @m4gic's comment might be correct, that the logging library is perhaps caching that interpolated string? It looks like you are using https://github.com/lightbend/scala-logging which claims that this interpolation "has no effect on behavior", so maybe not. Please could you follow his suggestion to retry without using that feature and report back?

A second possibility: I wonder if there is only one `ClusterHealthListener` in the system? Perhaps the autowiring is causing a second instance to be created? Can you log the [object ids](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)) of the `ClusterHealthListener` reference in both locations and verify that they are the same object?

If neither of those suggestions fix this, are you able to post a working example that I can play with?

Comment: Thanks. I tried what @m4gic suggested but didn't help. I logged the object ids and can see that it's the same instance.

I played around with the code a little more. I'm going to update the thread with my findings.

Comment: Let me see if i can take some part out for more context. It's proprietary code :(

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think the problem must be in some part of the code you haven't shown then, as the system you have described ought to work fine. If you can post a repro case that would really help to diagnose (and you may well diagnose it yourself as you isolate it). GL